# generate based on invalid table selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

In my application it creates a table and imports data and then writes to the database as shown in a part of the code below:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text.Contains(" "))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or contain spaces!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or contain spaces!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Currently importing " + textBox2.Text + "...\nA confirmation will be displayed when finished");

            string connectionString = "Data Source=bidb;Initial Catalog=STAGING;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox2.Text + "](" + "[Code] [varchar] (13) NOT NULL," +
           "[Description] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL," + "[NDC] [varchar] (255) NULL," +
            "[Supplier Code] [varchar] (38) NULL," + "[Supplier Description] [varchar] (255) NULL, " + "[UOM] [varchar] (8) NULL," + "[Size] [varchar] (8) NULL," + "[Progress][varchar](2) DEFAULT '0')";
}
```

Updated code from above:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(" "))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or contain spaces!");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or contain spaces!");
        }
        else
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=bidb;Initial Catalog=STAGING;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "](" + "ID int IDENTITY (1,1)," + "[Code] [varchar] (13) NOT NULL," +
           "[Description] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL," + "[NDC] [varchar] (50) NULL," +
            "[Supplier Code] [varchar] (50) NULL," + "[Supplier Description] [varchar] (255) NULL," + "[UOM] [varchar] (8) NULL," + "[Size] [varchar] (8) NULL,)";


            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Table Created in Database successfully!");
            this.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

After that it saves to a database as mentioned before. After it is created. In another part of my code it loads a comboBox of the table that was created which updates the column "progress" to a default value of zero. To better understand that here is the snippet of code:

```
 {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox4.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot reset previous value on an empty record,\n please load a table!");
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex -= 1;
        string connectionString2 = "Data Source=bidb;Initial Catalog=STAGING;Integrated Security=True";
        string query2 = "UPDATE dbo.[" + comboBox4.Text + "] SET Progress= '0' where code = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'; ";
```

Code that fills with the respective tables:

```
 private void FillCombo()
    {



        comboBox4.Items.Clear();



        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=bidb;Initial Catalog=STAGING;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                    comboBox4.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
                    //con2.Close();
                }
                // comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Ok that is good and fine but my issue is that yes it loads the table from the comboBox but it also loads other tables that exist from the table. This is where the problem occurs. if I choose any other table within that comboBox listhen the application crashes. This is because that the code that sets the progress column to a default value of zero doesn't exist as is expected in the other tables from the database. It would only be in the table I originally created from my application. How would I handle this error so that if the user selects a table other than the one that is actually created originally in my application then it can tell them that "this is table selection is invalid." Basically some error message of that kind. How would I approach this?

Comment: But how do you fill that combobox4? The point is here. Fill it only with valid names using the connection.GetSchema method and checking which table has the valid columns. As second note. Your code is a party for any practitioner of Sql Injection

Comment: `1. learn to create Parameterized query and or create your update statment and select statement and create statement's inside of a separate stored procedure` `2. store connection string inside of app.config or web.config file``3. Display or show us the exact error message`

Comment: @MethodMan noted. Will practice those suggestions. As for the error message, there is none. Application just freezes because I selected another table than the one that was created earlier

Comment: change this `textBox2.Text.` to check `if(textBox2.Text.Length <=0){ }`
or change it to check `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)){ return;}`

Comment: @Steve noted. Fill it with only valid values based ont he GetSchema method? How would I go about this?

Comment: if you are going to display code, please show all relevant code as it pertains to your current issue. for example.. where are you executing the code that calls the Create Table command? this code is incomplete and basically leads to guess work from others who look at it and try to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216564/use-sqlconnection-getschema-to-get-tables-only-no-views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720707/getschemacolumns-return-datatype and finally MSDN with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MethodMan I updated it to show where it is being executed

Comment: @Steve thank you but I don't believe that really speaks to my problem as I only want certain tables to be displayed as mentioned before.

Comment: And again, how do you fill that combobox? Why you have invalid tables to choose from? How do you identify the tables to add to your combo using only the name provided by your user? You need to know if the tables have the field you require in your code. You can do that when you fill the combo (making life easier for your user) or you can do that before executing the code that uses the field. Your choice

Comment: @Steve the comboBox is just filled by getting all the tables from the said database using the GetSchema and currently yes tthe table to be selected is identified by the name the user initially gave it upon creation. Invalid tables are there because everything is stored on this one database. If it was a case where this was a different database dedicated to that alone then the problem would not exist.

Comment: Actually there is a better way to get the tables that contain a specific column. It is a query against the system view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMS:  _select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'Progress'_

Comment: There are just so many things wrong here. The table name validation alone is not even close to satisfactory. You can't start a table name with a number, you are currently allowing single quotes in the table name. But regardless why are you allowing tables to be created whenever somebody has a whim? And the structure is the same every single time. This screams of horrible design. It sounds like what you really need is a new column in your table, not a new table over and over. Then there is sql injection...you are wide open. This needs a total rethinking.

Comment: @SeanLange noted. I'll correct this, as I am practicing as I go along. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said more than once in the comment above, your code has a lot of problems that vary from Sql Injection to missing validation of correct names.
Solving all these problems could escalate this answer to a whole article so I limit myself to provide you with a simple method to have a list of just the tables that contains the two fields required by your final code.

With this code you could fill the combobox4 with only valid table names.
*(IE tables that have both the column Progress and the column Code)*

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT table_name, count(table_name) 
                                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                         WHERE column_name = 'Progress' OR 
                                               column_name = 'Code'
                                         GROUP BY table_name
                                         HAVING count(table_name) > 1",
                        connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
combobox4.DataSource = dt;
combobox4.DisplayMember = "table_name";
```

Be sure to have, at least, the comboboxes involved to be not editable from the end user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take  a look at this and get back to you with my feedback. On a side note I updated my post with the code that loads the tables. I don't know if you want to take a look and yes the comboBoxes are not editable

Comment: Well, you can simply change the query with the one above and it should work.